# how can I prove that when I don't have a function?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

$f\colon X\to Y$. The following are equivalent:
(i) $f$ is injective;
(ii) $x=x'$ whenever $f(x) = f(x')$;
(iii) $f(x)\neq f(x')$ whenever $x\neq x'$.

As answer I've written:
let $x,x'$ be an element of $X$.  If $f$ is injective $f(x)=f(x')$ then $x=x'$.
We can also write it as $x\neq x'$ implying that $f(x)\neq f(x')$.

Then I was thinking of giving an example where I prove $f(x)=f(x')$.
But now I don't know how to prove the ($\neq$) part. should I give another example of such function?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use MathJax to type in math mode. I do not see any proof when you write 'If $f$ is injective $f(x)=f(x')$ then $x=x'$', unless your definition of injectivity is exactly that. But then (i) and (ii) would be exactly the same and there would be nothing to prove.

Comment: You need to prove that it's true for all functions.

Answer (score 1):

(i) and (ii) are equivalent because of the definition of injectivity. (iii) and (ii) are equivalent because (iii) is the contraposition if (ii).

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you're trying to prove something, adding an example may not be helpful to your proof (even if in some cases it might be clarifying).

If you have some problems proving (ii)->(iii), remember that whenever $A\implies B$ then $\neg B \implies \neg A$

(¬ is the "not" symbol)